# How do you find the major and minor numbers for devices in linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Trying to get access to a partially rooted Galaxy S2 external sd card.

The problem is that /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 does not exist on the phone.  This is the device name that should allow me to put the "recovery" image onto the sdcard so that the unit will be a phone again.

Problem is, I don't know where to find the magic Major and Minor numbers for this device and I'm trying to figure out where in the kernel source I should be looking for them.

Could someone point me at the right kernel files to find this information?

Answer (score 1):

Standard devices use predefined major numbers and minor numbers starting from 0 for the first instance and upward depending on how many instances there are going to be.

Look at the Linux Documentation file([devices.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devices.txt)) to see the full list but the section of interest to you is:

```
179 block       MMC block devices
          0 = /dev/mmcblk0      First SD/MMC card
          1 = /dev/mmcblk0p1    First partition on first MMC card
          8 = /dev/mmcblk1      Second SD/MMC card
            ...

        The start of next SD/MMC card can be configured with
        CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS, or overridden at boot/modprobe
        time using the mmcblk.perdev_minors option. That would
        bump the offset between each card to be the configured
        value instead of the default 8.
```

So /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 would be major 179, minor 9.

Comment: 179 and 8 don't appear to work, might be a problem with clockwork recover loader, don't know yet.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's 179 and **9** for the first partition of second SD card. A minor of 8 would be the entire SD card.

Answer (score 1):

According to [hotplug.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt)

> Entries for block devices are found at the following locations:
>
> /sys/block/*/dev
>   /sys/block/*/*/dev

So try looking in /sys/block/mmcblk1p1/dev.

EDIT:
Looking at it again I actually think that it will be in /sys/block/mmcblk1/mmcblk1p1/dev